# Android Studio space between my spinner and page title

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

I recently started using Android Studio because I wanted to create an app for my Android device.
I chose the bottom navigation activity as a template and added a spinner. I put the spinner in the highest possible position under the page title, but when I launch the app from debugging on my Android 10 phone, there is a large white space between my spinner and my page title. But there isn't any in the preview.
I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T Global if that matters.

My fragment Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.myfragment.MyFragment"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/myspinner"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Preview in the android studio**

[image: preview in android studio]

**what it looks like in the app**

[image: what it looks like in app]

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **removing** `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"` from your constraintLayout.
Absolute layout lets you specify exact locations (x/y coordinates) of its children.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work... Maybe there's just something wrong with my Dimensions of the Phone and the preview... I couldn't select the exact values in Android Studio, so I chose the closest. My Phone is 6.3" (diagonally) 1080 x 2340, so closest is Pixel 5, isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure you are not including another toolbar?

Comment: Try to share you main activity xml file maybe there's the problem

Comment: omg thanks you made me look again into the main activity.xml and there was a line: `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">` I removed it and there was no more space between, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove below lines from your code to solve the issue::

tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"

app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

Comment: Didn't work either... Maybe I gotta change something here? https://ibb.co/tbLYwYL

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve the issue::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/myspinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:entries="@array/spinnnerItem"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't change anything? I also tried removing the Constraints, so it would jump to 0,0, but there was still just a big white box between the top and the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

It generally works alike it is (without the messy preview settings):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/myspinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

While the actual difference is, that the Activity has a different theme than the XML preview. The one theme has an `ActionBar` - and the other one doesn't (some `.NoActionBar` theme). So you may want to apply the same theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`, which you use for the the XML preview.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into my MainActivity.xml file and there was a line of Code: `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">` just remove it and no more white bar!

Credits to [franvillacis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15386464/franvillacis), who made me look again into my MainActivity.xml